# how to set first row as a bold when fatch data using while loop in php

Tags: php

I wants my first row only display in big fonts and the other fetch data (rows) in small fonts...

this is my code:

```
<?php
$tasktable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskstatus != 'Done' AND assignedto = '". $uname ."'  ORDER BY taskduedate,taskpriority,taskcategory");
    echo "<table border = '0' align='center' style='font-family:Calibri;'>";
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#82CAFF'><td align='center' style='font-size:15px;'><b>Assigned Date</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Task Time</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Task Name</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Category</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Priority</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Estimated Time</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Status</b></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:15px;' ><b>Update</b></td></tr>";
       $i=0;
       while($task = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($tasktable)){ 
         if($i==0) { 
         $i=1;
         echo 'active';} 
         echo "<tr bgcolor='#F0FFFF' font-family:Calibri>";
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
            $taskduedate =  $task ['taskduedate'];
            echo $taskduedate;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
            $taskduetime =  $task ['taskduetime'];
            echo $taskduetime;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";
            $taskname =  $task ['taskname'];
            echo $taskname;
            echo "</td><td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";
            $taskcategory =  $task ['taskcategory'];
            echo $taskcategory;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
            $taskpriority =  $task ['taskpriority'];
            echo $taskpriority;
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
            $estimatedtime =  $task ['estimatedtime'];
            echo $estimatedtime;
            echo "</td>";   
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
            $taskstatus =  $task ['taskstatus'];
            echo $taskstatus;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:11px;'><a href='#'>";   
            echo "Update";
            echo "</a></td>";
           $i++;
       }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

But its not working. I don't get it. So,Please help me!
Thank you.

Comment: are you trying with <th> for table headers column?

Comment: You should use CSS instead of inline styles, and for the header row just use th instead of td, though I'm not sure why your code is not working.

Comment: when the result are display in table was all rows are same size.

Comment: when the while loop fetch all data....
Its display all rows are same size but

I want only first row big fonts and then another all fetched rows in small size...

Comment: Thanks guys....!
simply (if...else...) coding through my query was sort out...

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];

$tasktable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskstatus != 'Done' AND assignedto = '". $uname ."'  ORDER BY taskduedate,taskpriority,taskcategory");
echo "<table>";
while($task = mysql_fetch_array($tasktable)) 
    {
    if ($i == 1)
    {
       echo "<tr bgcolor='#F0FFFF' font-family:Calibri>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";   
        $taskduedate =  $task ['taskduedate'];
        echo $taskduedate;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";   
        $taskduetime =  $task ['taskduetime'];
        echo $taskduetime;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";
        $taskname =  $task ['taskname'];
        echo $taskname;
        echo "</td><td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";
        $taskcategory =  $task ['taskcategory'];
        echo $taskcategory;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";   
        $taskpriority =  $task ['taskpriority'];
        echo $taskpriority;
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";   
        $estimatedtime =  $task ['estimatedtime'];
        echo $estimatedtime;
        echo "</td>";   
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:25px;'>";   
        $taskstatus =  $task ['taskstatus'];
        echo $taskstatus;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td><div>Time: <span id='time'></span></div><input type='button' value='start' onclick='show();start();'>
    <input type='button' value='stop' onclick='stop();'>
    <input type='button' value='reset' onclick='reset()'></td>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#F0FFFF' font-family:Calibri>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
        $taskduedate =  $task ['taskduedate'];
        echo $taskduedate;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
        $taskduetime =  $task ['taskduetime'];
        echo $taskduetime;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";
        $taskname =  $task ['taskname'];
        echo $taskname;
        echo "</td><td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";
        $taskcategory =  $task ['taskcategory'];
        echo $taskcategory;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
        $taskpriority =  $task ['taskpriority'];
        echo $taskpriority;
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
        $estimatedtime =  $task ['estimatedtime'];
        echo $estimatedtime;
        echo "</td>";   
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px;'>";   
        $taskstatus =  $task ['taskstatus'];
        echo $taskstatus;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:11px;'><a href='#'>";   
        echo "Update";
        echo "</a></td>";

    }
    $i = $i+1;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```